# Displaying data from MYSQL database in a table (not separately)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to display my values from my database in a table. I've successfully managed to display the values below. But the tables are all separate from one another.

How do I combine them all into one table please?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'yourspace');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM profiles");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div style='border:solid 1px #ccc;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:10px;'>";
    echo "<table border='1'> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> 
<th>Age</th>
    <th>gender</th>
    <th>hometown</th>
    <th>University</th>
    <th>Occupation</th> </tr>";
    echo "<tr>";



echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['hometown'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['university'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['occupation'] . "</td>";

         echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
  echo "</div>";
}




mysqli_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be useful for clarity if you could show an example of how it currently displays, along with an example of how you would LIKE it to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First engage brain, then start coding.

You only want the table rows to be output as part of the loop.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'yourspace');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM profiles");

echo "<div style='border:solid 1px #ccc;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:10px;'>";
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Firstname</th> 
           <th>Lastname</th> <th>Age</th>
           <th>gender</th>
           <th>hometown</th>
           <th>University</th>
           <th>Occupation</th> 
      </tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['hometown'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['university'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['occupation'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";




mysqli_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! @riggsfolly

All of these is still new to me. Just started learning today! And wanted to get ahead actually. :)

Answer (score 0):

keep the table creation and ending part of table out of the while loop like this:

```
echo "<table border='1'> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> 
<th>Age</th>
<th>gender</th>
<th>hometown</th>
<th>University</th>
<th>Occupation</th> </tr>";

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {....
  //     print the records <Tr> <Td...... 
  }

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not performing the loop correctly. Infact for each record in your profile table you are creating `<table>` tags which is not good.

The correct way to do this is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'yourspace');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit(); //Exit not to display the table since there is an mysqli error
}
echo "<div style='border:solid 1px #ccc;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:10px;'>
    <table border='1'> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>gender</th>
    <th>hometown</th>
    <th>University</th>
    <th>Occupation</th> </tr>
    <tr>";
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM profiles");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['gender'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['hometown'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['university'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['occupation'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
echo "</div>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div style='border:solid 1px 
#ccc;padding:10px;float:left;margin-top:10px;'>";
echo "<table border='1'> <tr> <th>Firstname</th> <th>Lastname</th> 
<th>Age</th>
<th>gender</th>
<th>hometown</th>
<th>University</th>
<th>Occupation</th> </tr>";
```

This is your problem. While loop is running and from every time it runs it makes new table so you need to put this code outside of while loop, just before it. Inside while loop you just need to have code to add new columns in your existing table..